# Angular Firebase Getting ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am trying to build this function to upload a profile image at the Profile page of my application, the problem is that I'm getting `ZoneAwarePromise` as a result of the picture upload function. I've tried a bunch of different things but can't change the outcome.

Can anybody help me? What am I doing wrong?

**uploadService.ts**

```
pictureUpload(file: any, uid: string) {
    return this.afUpload.upload('profile/' + uid, file);
}
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
onCreateUser() {
    const picture = this.uploadService.pictureUpload(this.fileInput.nativeElement.files['0'], currentUserID).then(
      async (data) => {
        try {
          return data.ref.getDownloadURL();
        } catch {
          console.error();
        } finally {
          const email = this.userProfileForm.value.email;
          const firstName = this.userProfileForm.value.firstName;
          const lastName = this.userProfileForm.value.lastName;

          const userObj = {
            'uid': currentUserID,
            'email': email,
            'firstName': firstName,
            'lastName': lastName,
            'picture': picture
          };

          console.log('the object is');
          console.log(userObj);

          if (this.editMode) {
            return this.db.object('profile/' + currentUserID).update(userObj).then(
              () => {
                return this.presentToaster('Dados atualizados');
              },
              (e) => {
                this.presentToaster(e);
                console.error(e);
              }
            );
          } else {
            const load = await this.loadCtrl.create({
              message: 'Criando Usuario'
            });
            await load.present();
            return this.db.object('profile/' + currentUserID).set(userObj).then(
              () => {
                load.dismiss();
                return this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('news');
              },
              (error) => {
                load.dismiss();
                this.presentToaster(error);
                console.error(error);
              }
            );
          }
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it.

***Disclaimer: This is my first Firebase project, so all the description below is based on my observations. If I'm wrong about anything, please correct me, I'm looking to really understand this. Thanks :)***

Basically when I get the `try` I expect to get data back, in this case `data.ref.getDownloadURL()`. Because that's going to be a promise, I used the `.then` method to receive the "complete" data and then ran everything else inside that response. I seems like that data only exists there.

```
onCreateUser(uForm: FormGroup) {
    const currentUserID = this.userAuth.getCurrentUserID();
    let picture;
    this.uploadService.pictureUpload(this.fileInput.nativeElement.files['0'], currentUserID).then(
      async (data) => {
        try {
          data.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
            async (downloadURL) => {
              picture = downloadURL;
              const email = this.userProfileForm.value.email;
              const firstName = this.userProfileForm.value.firstName;
              const lastName = this.userProfileForm.value.lastName;

              const userObj = {
                'uid': currentUserID,
                'email': email,
                'firstName': firstName,
                'lastName': lastName,
                'picture': picture
              };

              if (this.editMode) {
                return this.db.object('profile/' + currentUserID).update(userObj).then(
                  () => {
                    return this.presentToaster('Dados atualizados');
                  },
                  (e) => {
                    this.presentToaster(e);
                    console.error(e);
                  }
                );
              } else {
                const load = await this.loadCtrl.create({
                  message: 'Criando Usuario'
                });
                await load.present();
                return this.db.object('profile/' + currentUserID).set(userObj).then(
                  () => {
                    load.dismiss();
                    return this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('news');
                  },
                  (error) => {
                    load.dismiss();
                    this.presentToaster(error);
                    console.error(error);
                  }
                );
              }
              //
            }
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

  }
```